# Cocoa thread cannot access Cocoa API

Tags: multithreading, cocoa

I am starting a new thread from the

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
```

method, using

```
MyThread *thread1 = [[MyThread alloc] init] ;
[thread1 start] ;
```

where `MyThread` is a subclass of `NSThread`.

If I run an empty `for` loop in the thread's `main` method and quit, it works fine. But as soon as I try to use a Cocoa API such as `NSString` or even `NSAutoReleasePool`, my program just hangs by entering the debugger.

What could be the source of the problem ?

[Hint]: I tried stepping thru the debugger and it once gave me a `SIGBUS` error. What memory access issues could there be ?

Comment: Are you setting up an autorelease pool in your thread [as per the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH15-SW16)?

Comment: @Adam Rosenfeld: “But as soon as I try to use … `NSAutoReleasePool`, my program just hangs by entering the debugger.”

Comment: Please edit your question to include the stack trace from the debugger. Also, you should try running your app under Instruments's Zombies template—if you have over-released or under-retained something, that'll reveal it swiftly, and then you can look into the object's history to find out what you did wrong.

Comment: There must be something causing this somewhere else. It's working fine for me

Comment: The problem was tricky. I was declaring a large char array of 1 MB in the middle of my main() method. The compiler was pushing this declaration to the top of the compiled method. Somehow this space was too large to ask for and hence the program would crash immediately upon entering the main method. Unfortunately, even when I inserted a return statement much before this declaration, the program would crash because the compiler would push this declaration to the very beginning. I changed that array declaration to a malloc() and the program ran.

Comment: @euphoria83 When you declare an array within a function or method, it is created on the stack. The default stack size for a thread must be smaller than 1 MB, so the OS wouldn't let you create the array there. Using `malloc` stores the data on the heap, which can be much larger than the stack. You should probably post your comment as an answer and accept it for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was tricky. I was declaring a large char array of 1 MB in the middle of my main() method. The compiler was pushing this declaration to the top of the compiled method. Somehow this space was too large to ask for and hence the program would crash immediately upon entering the main method. Unfortunately, even when I inserted a return statement much before this declaration, the program would crash because the compiler would push this declaration to the very beginning. I changed that array declaration to a malloc() and the program ran.